# WinRT ListView with itemsource as List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> error XAML (Windows 8.1 Universal App (XAML/C#))

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, winrt-xaml

I cant get this to work...  (Windows 8 Universal App (XAML/C#) project)
I have a listview that is bound to a List < KeyValuePair < string ,  string > >
here is the code:

```
                    <ListView 
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}" 
                       SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       >
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Light" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

and here is my C# code:

```
  private List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _languages;
public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Languages
{
    get
    {
        if (_languages == null)
        {
            _languages = Utils.AvailableLanguages;
        }

        return _languages;
    }
}

public KeyValuePair<string, string> SelectedLanguage
{
    get
    {
        return Languages.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == Utils.CurrentLanguage);
    }
    set
    {
        Utils.CurrentLanguage = value.Key;
        Api.Localization = value.Key;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentLanguage);
    }
}
```

In my listview if I do a "Binding Value" I get nothing (no data is shown), however if i do Binding without the Value element it shows me both the Key and the Value of my List :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Light" />
```

it showns me this: [image: http://i.imgur.com/F5ecYJI.png]

How do i make it so that i show only the Value of my list and not the key? thank you for your help!

Edit:
if i do this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding key}" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Light"  />
```

or that

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding value}" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Light"  />
```

same bug, :
 [image]

Edit2:
Utils.AvailableLanguages value:
 [image]

Comment: Hummm {Binding value} is the good thing.

Comment: {Binding key} what do you get?

Comment: I updated my question, i get an empty list with key and/or value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does indeed seem like the binding can't extract the property values - possibly because the types are generic. This is what you can see in VS Output window:

```
`A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Error: Cannot get 'Value' value (type 'String') from type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.CLRIKeyValuePairImpl`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. BindingExpression: Path='Value' DataItem='System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.CLRIKeyValuePairImpl`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String').
```

`key` and `value` would be the fields of `KeyValuePair` while bindings only work with properties, so that wouldn't work. The simple solution is to not use `KeyValuePair`. You should instead create your own class to hold the language code and country name. If they are both unique - you could simply use a list of strings like this:

**XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App51.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView
            x:Name="lv">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**C#**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App51
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            var kvps = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            kvps.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ar", "Argentina"));
            kvps.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("au", "Australia"));
            kvps.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("be-fr", "Belgique"));
            this.lv.ItemsSource = kvps.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

If there are fewer values than keys - you'd have to do something more like this:

**XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App51.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView
            x:Name="lv">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**C#**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App51
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            var kvps = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            kvps.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ar", "Argentina"));
            kvps.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("au", "Australia"));
            kvps.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("be-fr", "Belgique"));
            this.lv.ItemsSource = kvps.Select(kvp => new { kvp.Key, kvp.Value }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{Binding key} or {Binding value}
```

you can reduce code by this

```
get
{
    return _languages ?? (_languages = Utils.AvailableLanguages);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code reduce =), trying {Binding key} or {Binding value} was what i did at first however Visual Studio tells me to add a capital letter at Key and/or Value: http://i.imgur.com/fIM5Jfp.png

Comment: how did you init the property: AvailableLanguages? this is what i do: _availableLanguages = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ar", "Argentina"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("au", "Australia")  bla bla bla

Comment: I pasted your code and it works as well. I checked it in WPF now I noticed you were talking about WinRT so apparently it must differ slighlty.

Comment: yes i am using this in a Windows 8.1 Universal App (XAML/C#)